# bash script within EOF unable to pass arguments to function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following bash script, it is running in a file named some_file.sh, the contents look like

```
sudo -i -u $USER bash << EOF


func(){
    echo $1

}

func 'Test message for channel'

EOF
```

This returns nothing in the argument for the function even though the function is invoked with an argument, what am I doing wrong?

To invoke it I do

```
bash some_file.sh
```

Comment: how do you invoke it?

Comment: @mahatmanich I do bash some_file.sh

Comment: @Inder : The HERE-document is basically like a double-quoted string and undergoes parameter expansion. Hence, `$1` is already expanded before _sudo_ is invoked. If you would call it as `bash some_file.sh FOO`, you would see the effect of the expansion better.

Comment: @user1934428 valuable insight, thanks for that clarification it was really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the `<< 'EOF'` to prevent the `$` in the function from being expanded before the function is defined.

```sh
sudo -i -u $USER bash << 'EOF'

func(){
    echo $1
}

func 'Test message for channel'

EOF
```

See the Bash manual on [Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).  This behaviour applies to all Bourne shell derivatives — Bash, POSIX shells, `ksh`, etc.